Python is running an io task in paralell possible, which requires a for loop inevitably?
let me clarify my problem with bullet points.

In PyTorch(or whatever the reason), I'm making a Dataset class
I need to get all paths of the images in folder
but the images are structured under several subfolders
So the actual code I'm using is

p = Path(self.root_dir) / "Training" if self.is_train else "Validation"

image_p = p / "01.원천데이터" / f"{"T" if self.is_train else "V"}S_images"
label_p = p / "02.라벨링데이터" / f"{"T" if self.is_train else "V"}L_labels"

# set the return lists
image_path_list = []
label_list = []

# get image paths
for sentence_dir in image_p.glob("*"):  # only have several subfolders
    for true_false_dir in sentence_dir.glob("*"):  # only have several subfolders too                
        for posture_dir in true_false_dir.glob("*"):  # only have several subfolders again
            image_path = sorted(list(posture_dir.glob("*")))[-1]  # in 'posture_dir', there are images, but I need only the last one
            image_path_list.append(str(image_path))


What is important here, is that I need to go deep down to the very bottom of the subfolders to get the actual path of an image

Is there any way I could make this execution faster?
Most of the resources about multiprocessing or multithreading seem to have a concept of vectorising a function with a list type of argument passed, but not sure if that would fit with my situation now...

Typically this kind of task isn't a good candidate for parallelization -- the bottlenecks end up being in the filesystem syscalls. Once your I/O paths are full, more threads won't make things any faster because they're waiting for the same devices/locks/&c. sorted itself might be a CPU-bound component, but you'll get more performance gain by just not doing the sorting rather than trying to parallelize it

(or at least, not blocking whatever work you're doing on the paths you retrieve on completing the sorting; if, for example, you start a background task or create a queue entry for each file you find that you want to process, you can do the sorting later, while those queue entries are being processed, so starting the work isn't blocked on the sort operations)

...that's particularly important because you can't sort a list until you finished retrieving the entire list, whereas if you start processing files the moment they come back from the OS's syscalls, you can be kicking off the processing work while some of the listdir operations are still pending. Analyzing the bottlenecks in your process is generally a better place to start than just trying to throw more parallelism at an issue.

(I also would generally avoid glob("*") -- that's invoking codepaths meant to do filtering in a scenario where you don't need any filtering)

image_path_list = list(image_p.glob("**/*"))

The glob pattern ** matches any depth. This is pretty fast, as it is fully implemented in C, and should not need parallelisation (especially compared to anything else you are likely to do with the result).
In general, you might want to iterate over the generator instead of converting it into a list if the list would consume inordinate amount of memory though; but since you say you are creating a pytorch Dataset, which needs to implement random access via __getitem__, it might not be the best approach here; straight up list works better.

I think this is a precursor to making a collection purely to immediately use it - if they can start early, they might consider iglob, feeding a thread pool, multiprocessing queue, asyncio tasks, etc.

@Amadan as other comments are suggesting, can I assume that you mean there is not a particular part in this task to be parallelised?

I can't answer that; that might depend on your storage device, and the implementation of glob, which I haven't seen. Instead, what I mean is that reading the filelist would take insignificant time next to actually loading and putting those files through a torch pipeline. I.e. I suggest you are worrying about optimising something that will give you marginal gains, if any. "We should forget about small efficiencies, say about 97% of the time: premature optimization is the root of all evil. Yet we should not pass up our opportunities in that critical 3%" and this doesn't appear to be in the 3%.

I don't know why it is so, but your answer and my original code using 3 for loops seem to be not different much in terms of speed.

Your answer was faster when executed first before my original code
But my original code ran faster when that was executed first before your answer

But, anyway it helped the code to be simpler

That should be due to kernel caching, I believe (though I am not an expert in kernel). Once you ask kernel to find the files, the next time it will give you the result much more efficiently. This might be relevant.
